# Polkadot JS query response types are missing

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template, substrate-node, types

No types for blockchain query responses are available in our IDE.
Doing any query like this

```
await blockchain.api.query.assets.asset(id, (res) => {
    const info = res.toJSON()
    console.log("asset info", info)
})
```

the res variable is undefined.

i have my types available and can see api.query.assets and all the available functions like .asset but there are no return types.
We have to manually type them like

```
const info:PalletAssetsAssetDetails = res.toJSON()
```

Comment: ok so it turns out we were stuck on an old version of the @polkadot/typegen and it was messing things up We updated to current version and its working for base generic substrate chain now. Next we gotta get our custom chain working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is to apply augmentation, for that you have to import '@polkadot/api-augment' into your codebase entry point before any imports from the API itself:

```js
import "@polkadot/api-augment";
```

See the docs from PolkadotJS: [Since upgrading to the 7.x series, TypeScript augmentation is missing](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/FAQ/#since-upgrading-to-the-7x-series-typescript-augmentation-is-missing).

Now you will see that res has a type: `Option<PalletAssetsAssetDetails>` (An Option attempts to mimic the Rust approach of having None and Some available), you can get your values like that:

```js
api.query.assets.asset(id, (res: any) => {
      const asset = res.unwrap();
      console.log(asset.owner.toString());
}
```

Comment: the toHuman doesnot give me any Types.  I am using toHuman for the metadata like: 
  name: res.name.toHuman() as any[][0]   
I still need the types from somewhere and the query response does not have them. The response is types as    any

Comment: Sorry you were right, I misunderstood what you were looking for. I have edited my response

Comment: i have the ```import "@polkadot/api-augment"``` in my app.tsx before importing anything and no types on the response...

Comment: at first we were following this example https://github.com/polkadot-js/docs/tree/master/docs/api/examples/promise/typegen

Comment: ok so it turns out we were stuck on an old version of the @polkadot/typegen and it was messing things up. it works for the generic substrate chain now. Next we gotta get our custom chain working. thank you.